# How to make a view scrollable which contains swipe refresh layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to make a view scrollable which contains a swipe refresh layout. My xml is here

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_post" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But it doesn't shows content's of `recycler-view`. Only shows content's of `Cardview`
[image]
Without using `NestedScrollView` it show's like below. It show's both contents of cardivew and recyler view. But I want to make my whole screen scrollable. What I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Why using nestedscrollview?

Comment: @SumitShukla I'm a noob in Android. But using `scroll view` gives me same output as `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 2):

The SwipeRefreshLayout will take the full height, you need to add it as the parent for your xml in your case as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_post" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: But it shows as my first image. Contents of `recycler view` is not showing?

Comment: Im not sure what is exactly happening with you butmake sure you set the recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

Comment: @ShahrearBinAmin